# Create custom TypeConverter for different Types

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Hi I'm stuck thinking how I can achieve the following:

I need to create a component 'ControlValidator' that extends a property called `Validator` which type is `ValidatorBase`, the property should be displayed in the Property Grid as a ComboBox with the following values `{None, Required Field, Regular Expression}` where:

- None = No Validations
- Required Field = Class that extends from `ValidatorBase`
- Regular Expression = Class that extends from `ValidatorBase`

This is the property grid with the code I have, it shows the property as I want but I can't set Validation1 to 'none' and if I try to save the form, it says that the Button which I assigned the property is generating a null value:

[image]

Here's the code I have, I'm so confused haha.

Thanks!!

ControlValidator

```
<ProvideProperty("Validation1", GetType(Control))>
Public Class ControlValidator
    Inherits Component

    Implements IExtenderProvider

    Private helpTexts As Hashtable

    Public Sub New()
        helpTexts = New Hashtable
    End Sub

    Public Function CanExtend(extendee As Object) As Boolean Implements IExtenderProvider.CanExtend
        If TypeOf extendee Is Control AndAlso Not TypeOf extendee Is ControlValidator Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    <DefaultValue(GetType(ValidatorsBase), "None")>
    Public Function GetValidation1(ByVal ctrl As Control) As ValidatorsBase
        Dim myText As ValidatorsBase = helpTexts(ctrl)

        If myText Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return myText
    End Function

    Public Sub SetValidation1(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal value As ValidatorsBase)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            helpTexts.Remove(ctrl)
        Else
            helpTexts(ctrl) = value
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

ValidatorsBase

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ValidatorsConverter))>
Public Class ValidatorsBase
    Private _errorText As String
    Public Property ErrorText() As String
        Get
            Return _errorText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _errorText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Validator"
    End Function
End Class
```

Required Field Class:

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ValidatorsConverter))>
Public Class RequiredField
    Inherits ValidatorsBase

    Private _required As Boolean
    Public Property required() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _required
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _required = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Required Field"
    End Function
End Class
```

TypeConverter:

```
Public Class ValidatorsConverter
    Inherits TypeConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType As Type) As Boolean
        Return destinationType = GetType(InstanceDescriptor) OrElse MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CanConvertFrom(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, sourceType As Type) As Boolean
        Return sourceType = GetType(String) OrElse MyBase.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ConvertFrom(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As CultureInfo, value As Object) As Object
        Dim result As Object = Nothing

        If value Is Nothing OrElse value.ToString = "(none)" Then
            result = "(none)"
        ElseIf value.ToString = "Required Field" Then
            result = New RequiredField
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetPropertiesSupported(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value, attributes)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesSupported(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetStandardValues(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As StandardValuesCollection
        Dim values As New List(Of String)

        values.Add("(none)")
        values.Add("Required Field")

        Return New StandardValuesCollection(values)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I kind of follow what you are trying to do.  a) it might be easier if the Property added was an Enum like `ValidationRule` and internally, the code responded accordingly. b) you never create a `ValidatorsBase` object for your property c) when it is NONE, that property would always be null, no?  d) I dont think you need `GetPropertiesSupported` or `GetStandardValues` e) you dont implement the `InstanceDescriptor` ConvertTo

Comment: a) If the property is an Enum is there a way to display the properties `ErrorText` , `Required` , etc.. at design time according to the option I choose? b) `ValidatorsBase` is just a "template" for the other validators maybe I should use an interface c) Yes, it need to be null always d) I agree, if I use the enum I don't have to use that e) Really I don't know how to implement it .  Thanks for your answer @Plutonix

Comment: I'm still puzzling out implementation alternatives. but the flaw in your thinking is that a Property of Type `ValidatorBase` will allow you to set/get the Required field or RegEx text - it wont because they exist in other Types (maybe that was what GetProperties was for).  Even in code it will require too may gyrations to use (for my taste). At a minimum, I would implement a NullValidator that does nothing so the *Property* is never Nothing

Comment: Is the `RegularExpression` version actually RegEx based where the related property is RegEx text?

Comment: 1- I based the code in this 'tutorial', maybe it can help http://www.cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-custom-typeconverter-part-2
    2-The `RegularExpression` could be a `String`

Answer (score 1):

There area few flaws in your approach.  `ValidatorsBase` apparently also serves as the `ErrorText` version, and the `RegularExpression` Type is not shown.

- The property you are extending is of Type `ValidatorsBase`, but this will not allow you to set the `Required` nor `RegEx` text properties for the more specific types.  Those properties exist on *other* Types.
- If the property is left null for `None`, the VS IDE wont like it; nor will you because you will have to do lots of `If thisCrtl.Validator1 IsNot Nothing Then...`
- I dont know how these objects are used, but you are not creating any at all, so any designer assignments are lost.

---

If you abstract it a little, it appears there are maybe 3 pieces of info: **Validation Rule** (None, ErrorMsg, Required, RegEx), **Some text** used as either the msg or the RegEx depending on the Rule, **A Boolean** for Required.

So, using a simple class for these, with the basic `ExpandableObjectConverter` does close to what you want:

```
' simple, easy TypeConverter to expand the object to reveal the properties
<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
Public Class Validator
    Public Property Rule As ControlValidator.ValidationRule
    Public Property ValidationText() As String
    <Description("This field is Required By Law")>
    Public Property Required As Boolean

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(r As ControlValidator.ValidationRule)
        Rule = r
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Rule.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, the Extender:

```
<ProvideProperty("Validator", GetType(Control))>
Public Class ControlValidator
    Inherits Component
    Implements IExtenderProvider

    Public Enum ValidationRule
        None
        RequiredField
        RegularExpression
    End Enum

    Private helpTexts As Dictionary(Of Control, Validator)
```

(Tip: if you limit `CanExtend` to one control, like `TextBox` or `NumericUpDn` initially, you wont have hundreds of lines of designer code invalidated when you change your mind about a name or property type.)

Your Get/Set pair needs to create them:

```
<Category("Uber Validator"), DisplayName("Validator")>
<Description("Validation type to apply to this control")>
Public Function GetValidator(ByVal ctrl As Control) As Validator
    If helpTexts.ContainsKey(ctrl) Then
        Return helpTexts(ctrl)
    Else
        Return New Validator(ValidationRule.None)
    End If
End Function

Public Sub SetValidator(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal value As Validator)
    If helpTexts.ContainsKey(ctrl) Then
        helpTexts(ctrl) = value
    Else
        helpTexts.Add(ctrl, value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Decorated as shown, you can change the awful default display for Extended Properties:

[image]

*So far*, VS is able to serialize the `Validator` for us.  Designer code:

```
Validator2.Required = False
Validator2.Rule = ControlValidator.ValidationRule.None
Validator2.ValidationText = Nothing
Me.ControlValidator1.SetValidator(Me.nud2, Validator2)
```

As is, my `Validator` is little more than a holder for the info you appear to need.  This provides a variety of ways to use it though:

- That class could implement the validation logic conditionally based on the Rule
- The class could create "real" helper validaters internally
- Your code could fetch the data and create "real" validater objects from it

You might find an all-in-one Validator more useful: For instance, `ErrorText` might be useful for both `RegEx` and `Required` Rules.

Comment: Thank you so much @Plutonix, I'll check the code later!

Comment: 1. I have implemented the code but I'm getting an error in the Property Grid of the TextBox `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. 2. The `Public Class ControlValidator` declaration isn't missing the `<ProvideProperty("Validator", GetType(TextBox))>` ? 3. And yes ErrorText needs to be used in RegEx and Required rules. Thanks a lot @Plutonix

Comment: Here is the [error in the property grid](http://s12.postimg.org/qkzj24eyl/error.png)

Comment: There are only 2 objects which need to be instanced:  V Objects if they dont exist and `helptexts` which I did not show but used the Extender ctor just as you did.  That *looks like* the former since the entire extender will cease to work if you mess up `helptexts`.  Are you trying to use 1 or 3 V classes?  Put your code on pastebin and give me a link and I will look at it.

Comment: BTW, [here is another ExpandableConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32383919/1070452) with a little more functionality.  I am not sure how it would help with yours, and the answer was already long, so I left it out.  You *could* end up needing a TV in order to help with serialization.  So far it seems not to need it.  Upvote it if it helps (and everything and anything you ever google that helps or informs).

Comment: I've instantiated `helptexts` and it works fine now. Maybe I didn't explained well but what I want to achieve is  [something like this](http://s7.postimg.org/y703dylnf/validator.png), in the example every option 'invokes' a different class inherited from `ValidatorsBase` and in the property grid it shows its own properties

Comment: The code they generate in the designer [is the following](http://pastebin.com/F6xWY3GQ)

Comment: That is a different Validator than what you've posted.  Is there another piece to this aside from the extenderprovider and the V class(es) - perhaps a piece which will use the Validator objects?  A property can only have one Type, so the property which your extender adds can only be a `RequiredFieldValidator` **or** a `RegExValidator` etc.  You cant downcast to a base class as the OP tries to do and still access the more specific class properties.  A TypeConverter can convert classes to other representations `Cat` to `"Cat"` but not `Cat` object to `Bird` object even if they inherit aninal

Comment: What if the provided property is `Object` type, all the validators inherits from `ValidatorBase` and in the function `GetValidator` I ask for an `Object`type object? the question is: would visual Studio designer show the properties of each `ValidatorBase` inherited object?

Comment: Or I don't know, the guys that made the validator ask for a `ValidatorBase` Object in the `SetValidator`.  In the previous comment I wanted to say `SetValidator` instead of GetValidator

Comment: See?  I thought there was another piece.  The problem with using an extender for this is that you cant change the Type from ReqField to RegEx on the fly; downcasting to Object is worse because now you can get at any of the properties.  What you can do is what I explained in the answer - associate enough data with each to create VObjects from it.  A better way still might be to serialize the data for them,